# Difference between expr(mean(1:10)) and expr(mean(!!(1:10))

Tags: r, metaprogramming

Going through metaprogramming sections of Hadley's book Advanced R 2nd ed, I have quite a bit of a tough time understanding the concept. I have been programming with R for a while but this is the first time I came across the concept of metaprogramming. This exercise question in particular confuses me

"The following two calls print the same, but are actually different:

```
(a <- expr(mean(1:10)))
#> mean(1:10)
(b <- expr(mean(!!(1:10))))
#> mean(1:10)
identical(a, b)
#> [1] FALSE
```

What’s the difference? Which one is more natural?"

when I eval them they both returns the same

```
> eval(a)
[1] 5.5
> eval(b)
[1] 5.5
```

when I look inside the a and b object the second object does print differently, but I am not sure what does this mean in terms of their difference:

```
> a[[2]]
1:10
> b[[2]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

also if I just run them without eval(expr(...)) then it will return differently:

```
mean(1:10)
[1] 5.5
mean(!!(1:10))
[1] 1
```

My guess is that without expr(...) !!(1:10) act as a double negation which with coercion essentially forcing all the numbers to be 1, hence mean of 1.

My questions are:

1. Why does the !! acts differently with and without the expr(...) ? I would expect eval(expr(mean(!!(1:10)))) to return the same as mean(!!(1:10)) but this is not so
2. I still do not quite fully grasp what is the difference between a object and b object ?

thank you in advance

Comment: You can check with `all.equal`, both `expr` are same. The `!` converts to logical vector.  If there is any 0, it will be TRUE and others false.  With double `!`, the TRUE gets converted to FALSE and FALSE to TRUE.  With `1:10`, it is all `TRUE` and `mean(rep(TRUE, 10))#
[1] 1`

Answer (score 1):

`!!` here is used not as double negation, but the unquote operator from `rlang`.

> Unquoting is one inverse of quoting. It allows you to selectively
>   evaluate code inside expr(), so that expr(!!x) is equivalent to x.

The difference between `a` and `b` is that the argument remains as an unevaluated call in `a`, while it is evaluated in `b`:

```
class(a[[2]])
[1] "call"
class(b[[2]])
[1] "integer"
```

The `a` behaviour may be an advantage in some circumstances because it delays evaluation, or a disadvantage for the same reason. When it is a disadvantage, it is of the the cause of much frustration. If the argument was a larger vector, the size of `b` would increase, while `a` would stay the same.

See [section 19.4 of Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference.  When we negate (`!`) an integer vector, numbers other than 0 are converted to FALSE and 0 to TRUE.  With another negate ie. double (`!!`), the FALSE are changed to TRUE and viceversa

```
!0:5
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

!!0:5
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

With the OP's example, it is all `TRUE`

```
!!1:10
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

and TRUE/FALSE can be otherwise 1/0

```
as.integer(!!1:10)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

thus the `mean` would be 1

```
mean(!!1:10)
#[1] 1
```

---

Regarding the 'a' vs. 'b'

```
str(a)
#language mean(1:10)
str(b)
#language mean(1:10)
```

Both are language objects and it will be evaluated to get the `mean` of numbers 1:10

```
all.equal(a, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

If we need to get the `mean` of 10 numbers, the first one is the correct way.

We could `eval`uate the second option correctly i.e. getting a `mean` value of 1, by `quote`ing

```
eval(quote(mean(!!(1:10))))
#[1] 1
eval(quote(mean(1:10)))
#[1] 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

`!!` has special meaing when used inside `expr`.

outside `expr` you will get different results because
`!!` is a double negation

even inside `expr` the two versions are different because
`1:10` is an expression resulting in an integer vector
when evaluated, while `!!(1:10)` is the result of
evaluating this same expression.

an expression and its result after it is evaluated are
different things.

[image]